# Angular/RxJS type error when mapping observable

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, angular-calendar

I am getting the following error when trying to map a resposne from my api

```
Argument of type 'OperatorFunction<{ results: CustomerShipment[]; },{ title: string; start: Date; }[]>' 
is not assignable to parameter of type 'OperatorFunction<CustomerShipment[], {title:string; start: Date;}[]>'. 
Type '{ results: CustomerShipment[]; }' is missing the following properties from type 'CustomerShipment[]':
length, pop, push, concat, and 26 more.
```

API which returns a JSON array of objects with the following schema… I use Angular-Calendar v0.28.28

```
{
    "0": {
        "customerId": 1234,
        "customer": "test",
        "items": [
           id: 123,
           tssNumber: "1234567"
           containerNumber: "e.g.",
           appointmentTime: "23/03/2022 12:00 p.m."
        ]
    }
}
```

An angular calendar event has the following required properties: `start: Date`, `title: string`. I am trying to map the response from my API to the `CalendarEvent` object :

```
events$: Observable<CalendarEvent<{ results: CustomerShipment }>[]>;

ngAfterViewInit(): void 
{
   this.fetchCustomers(formatDate(this.viewDate, 'yyyy-MM-dd', 'en'));
}

fetchData(day: string): void {
let params = new HttpParams();
params = params.append('userid', this.getUserId());
params = params.append('date', day);
 this.events$ = this.calendarService.getDailyCalendarShipments(params)
   .pipe(
      map(({ results }: { results: CustomerShipment[] }) => {
        return results.map((result: CustomerShipment) => {
          return {
            title: result.customer,
            start: new Date()
          };
        });
   }));
}
```

then in the HTML component

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div #scrollContainer class="scroll-container" *ngIf="events$ | async; else loader; let events">
    <app-day-view-scheduler (eventTimesChanged)="eventTimesChanged($event)"
                            (userChanged)="userChanged($event)"
                            [events]="events"
                            [headers]="headers"
                            [viewDate]="viewDate">
    </app-day-view-scheduler>
  </div>
</div>
```

I can do this without using the Observable, but I want to use the angular `async` pipe.

I'm using the following example: https://mattlewis92.github.io/angular-calendar/#/async-events

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getDailyCalendarShipments` returning array of type CustomerShipment

Used `from` to emit data in sequence and `mergeMap` to subscribe this

inside `map` creating your event of type `{ results: CustomerShipment }`

`toArray` creating `{ results: CustomerShipment }[]`

```
this.events$ = this.calendarService.getDailyCalendarShipments(params).pipe(
  mergeMap(({ results }: { results: CustomerShipment[] }) => {
    return from(results);
  }),
  map((result: CustomerShipment) => {
    return {
      title: result.customer,
      start: new Date(),
    };
  }),
  toArray()
);
```

Comment: Okay, this fixes the error if I use `Observable<CalendarEvent[]>`, but I have issues when I try to access a sub array inside `CustomerShipment`. Each `CustomerShipment` can contain an array of items. I want to map that array of items into the return result. But when I do a separate map for it, there is once again an error:  `error TS2322: Type 'Observable<(void | CalendarEvent<any>)[]>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<CalendarEvent<any>[]>'.`

Comment: I posted this issue in a new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71600939/rxjs-angular-error-when-mapping-sub-array-in-observables

Answer (score 0):

You need either to change the type of the `events$` Observable to be `Observable<CalendarEvent<CustomerShipment>[]>`, or change the `map` operator output to be `CalendarEvent<{ results: CustomerShipment }>[]` like the following:

```js
this.events$ = this.calendarService.getDailyCalendarShipments(params).pipe(
  map(({ results }: { results: CustomerShipment[] }) => ({
    results: results.map((result: CustomerShipment) => ({
      title: result.customer,
      start: new Date(),
    })),
  }))
);
```

Comment: I've tried this but I more or less get the same error. The `calendarService.getDailyCalendarShipments(params)` returns `Observable<CustomerShipment[]>` if it helps